# PWA beforeinstallprompt not called

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, progressive-web-apps

Hello I'm using the default install prompt for my PWA but it doesn't seem to work.

The answers in [PWA - beforeinstallprompt not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50762626/pwa-beforeinstallprompt-not-called) are not working for me.

My manifest is not broken, service worker is registered, when I test the prompt in my browser on my computer it works like a charm but when I visit the site with my mobile phone, android 9, with the chrome browser, no popup is presented. I've cleared the cache many times without positive effect.

Any ideas?

`The PWA must not already be installed` -- it was but I've removed it from the phone and cleared the cache.

`Meets a user engagement heuristic (the user must have at least 30s interaction with your web app.` -- no idea how to fix this..

`Your web app must include a web app manifest.` -- it does, no errors,

`Your web app must be served over a secure HTTPS connection.` -- it is

`Has registered a service worker with a fetch event handler.` -- it has

Everything from [PWA - beforeinstallprompt not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50762626/pwa-beforeinstallprompt-not-called).

Comment: I suggest you run it on debug mode with your PC and an USB cable

Comment: Are you testing with a HTTPS site? That is a requirement. Are you sure there is no App icon with your other app icons? That needs to be removed in addition to clearing cache.

Comment: Does your app pass the Chrome lighthouse test as a valid PWA?

Comment: - im testing with MAMP. ive used a self signed certificate for this created by MAMP.

Comment: - well they are green, is there a difference for mobile vs desktop for the beforeinstallprompt for this?

Comment: Should be the same for both mobile & desktop. Self-signed certificate may be the problem. Valid HTTPS is a requirement you cannot get around. If it's a simple app you just want to test, upload it to a free HTTPS like https://glitch.com/

Comment: I think I have the same issue. When accessing the app link for the first time the beforeinstallprompt is not called. Users have to manually install it with "Add to home screen". Next time everything works propertly. I think it might be the 30 seconds timer.

@RuudVen have you solved your issue?

Comment: In my case, it works fine Edge but does not work on Chrome (Both desktop). Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong?